# can we able to specify on click on the component definition itself?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I want to create a component(comp) with onclick event handler. which should be handled by the component itself (i.e. inside the comp.js file).
if I use it inside the parent component we don't need to specify the event but it is handled by the component element(comp element).

is this possible. Any idea to develop this one.

in ParentComponent.js current behavior.

```
<NewComponent onClick={clickBehaviour}/>
```

I want like,
In NewComponent.js

```
const NewComponent.js = ()=>{
    // Some code
    const clickBehaviour = () =>{
        // click behaviour
    }
}
```

Is it possible in the current standards?

Answer (score 1):

why you want to write your onClick event in parent component?
you can do it inside NewComponent.js easily.
just do this:

```
import React from 'react'

function NewComponent() {

    const clickBehaviour = () =>{
        // click behaviour
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={clickBehaviour}>
            //some jsx here
        </div>
    )
}

export default NewComponent
```

and use in anywhere you want to use without onClick event :

```
< NewComponent />
```

i cant understand well you situation but you can use forwardRef if you want (also can use old getElementById but using forwardRef is recommended).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const NewComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div onClick={() => alert("div 2 clicked")} ref={ref}>
    div 2
  </div>
));
export default function App() {
  const compRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <NewComponent ref={compRef} onClick={() => {
          compRef && compRef.current && compRef.current.click();
        }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i need to create a draggable component which needs to use in multiple places. Instead of writing onclick on multiple place component files I can write on Component.js file so that I won't have to repeat

Comment: i cant understand well you situation but i think forwardRef is the thing you want. i update my answer, hope it help you